# Sys.ArgumentUndefinedException: Value cannot be undefined

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am developing some ajax stuff on asp.net mvc framework beta.

but,I got exception as following.
Anyone has problem like me?

Sys.ArgumentUndefinedException: Value cannot be undefined.

and my source code is like this.

```
<asp:Content ID="indexContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.2.6.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var myView;

    $(pageLoad);

    function pageLoad() {
        myView = $create(Sys.UI.DataView, {}, {}, {}, $get("ajaxResult"));
        $("#callAjaxButton").click(callActionMethod);
    }

    function callActionMethod() {
        $.getJSON("/Home/GetCategories", bindData);
    }

    function bindData(data) {
        myView.set_data(data);
    }

</script>

<input type="button" id="callAjaxButton" value="ajaxCall" />

<div id="ajaxResult"></div>    

</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1):

From the snippet you provided there are a couple of things to consider:

- You are missing a script reference to the [Microsoft ASP.NET 2.0 AJAX Templates for Visual Studio 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/Downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=5c7df430-1c34-40d2-b6ec-81353b5fcf2e&displaylang=en).
- You are using the jquery's [document.ready](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/ready) function (raised whenever the DOM is ready to be traversed and manipulated) instead of the [System.Application.init](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/Documentation/Live/ClientReference/Sys/ApplicationClass/SysApplicationInitEvent.aspx) event (raised after all scripts have been loaded but before objects are created).

Can you try this to see if it works for you:

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.2.6.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftAjaxTemplates.debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var myView;

    Sys.Application.add_init(pageLoad);

    function pageLoad() {
        myView = $create(Sys.UI.DataView, {}, {}, {}, $get("ajaxResult"));
        $("#callAjaxButton").click(callActionMethod);
    }

    function callActionMethod() {
        $.getJSON("/Home/GetCategories", bindData);
    }

    function bindData(data) {
        myView.set_data(data);
    }

</script>

<input type="button" id="callAjaxButton" value="ajaxCall" />
<div id="ajaxResult"></div>
```

[Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/) has written a nice [post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/jQueryToShipWithASPNETMVCAndVisualStudio.aspx) on this subject.