# AutoComplete not working

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I am using ajax auto complete extender on a textbox and I am also using calender extender on  other two textboxes and a jquery Image slider.But my autocomplete extender is not working . But when i use same code in new project it works well. My code on search control  is :

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Desired Location you want to Search?&nbsp;"></asp:Label></label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" onfocus="if(this.value=='Type Location Here !') this.value='';"
            onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Type Location Here !';" CssClass="txtbox"
            Width="520px">Type Location Here !</asp:TextBox>
              <asp:AutoCompleteExtender  ID="autosearch" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtSearch"
            ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList" CompletionSetCount="10" UseContextKey="true" ContextKey="SearchKey"
            Enabled="true" EnableCaching="true" MinimumPrefixLength="1" CompletionInterval="100"
            CompletionListCssClass="autocomplete_list" ScriptPath="SearchInputControl.ascx.cs" 
            CompletionListItemCssClass="autocomplete_listItem" CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="autocomplete_highlighted_listitem" >
        </asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

Javascript error:

```
Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; AskTbTRL2/5.15.4.23821) Timestamp: Thu, 1 Nov 2012 06:59:14 UTC     
Message: Sys.ArgumentUndefinedException: Value cannot be undefined. 
Parameter name: type Line: 4620 Char: 12 Code: 0
```

Comment: Do you get any javascript error ?

Comment: yes Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; AskTbTRL2/5.15.4.23821)
Timestamp: Thu, 1 Nov 2012 06:59:14 UTC


Message: Sys.ArgumentUndefinedException: Value cannot be undefined.
Parameter name: type
Line: 4620
Char: 12
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost:51745/hotelweb/ScriptResource.axd?d=WklTceeG5bKyt0e354YLzgBcsF7XVvYb8wXUBI3LscHKKm-lrB3kXOef2KkycdPE0&t=ffffffffe81e7100

Comment: search for `Sys.ArgumentUndefinedException: Value cannot be undefined` See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310964(VS.100).aspx , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/380389/sys-argumentundefinedexception-value-cannot-be-undefined , http://forums.asp.net/t/1709225.aspx/1

Answer (score 0):

looks like `onfocus` and `onblur` are your show stoppers. remove them and retry.

Basically, you can not directly add these events to asp.net textbox like this. use `txtSearch.Attributes.Add('onfocus','jscode')` way to add these events.

Comment: I removed onfocus and onblur on search textbox but its still not working.One more thing I am using onfocus and onblur on other two textboxes , am i supposed to remove from those also...thx

Comment: yes, basically you need to see your document loaded without any javascript errors

Comment: what javascript errors are you getting while you try to type text?

Comment: when I use autocomplete on search textbox , calender extender on other two textboxes stops working. and when i comment autocomplete on searchtextbox , Calender extenders on other two textboxes work fine.I am getting following error when page is loaded and when i type characters in search textbox error is same:

Comment: Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; AskTbTRL2/5.15.4.23821)
Timestamp: Thu, 1 Nov 2012 07:53:35 UTC


Message: Sys.ArgumentUndefinedException: Value cannot be undefined.
Parameter name: type
Line: 4620
Char: 12
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost:51745/hotelweb/ScriptResource.axd?d=WklTceeG5bKyt0e354YLzgBcsF7XVvYb8wXUBI3LscHKKm-lrB3kXOef2KkycdPE0&t=ffffffffe81e7100